# Create form and handle results in TYPO3 extension

Tags: forms, typo3, typo3-9.x

I am trying to find out what is the best approach for my task:

Create a form with validation, spamcheck etc. using existing functionality. The results of the form must be handled in an extension and sent to an external application via REST api. Additionally, an email should be sent.

I am still struggling with TYPO3 and would like some help for what might be a good approach. I would like to use existing functionality as much as possible and not reinvent the wheel.

- there is the [ext:form framework](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-form/master/en-us/). I saw that there are finishers, but not that it might be possible to send the results of the form to a Controller action
- if that is not possible, is it possible for my extension to get notified (e.g. signal / slot) when a form has been submitted
- alternatively, I could use [Fluid form ViewHelpers](https://docs.typo3.org/other/typo3/view-helper-reference/9.5/en-us/typo3/fluid/latest/Form/Index.html). I did not find much information about how to handle the validation
- [form.validationResults](https://docs.typo3.org/other/typo3/view-helper-reference/9.5/en-us/typo3/fluid/latest/Form/ValidationResults.html) : I don't exactly understand what it does.
- handle validation via JavaScript

Any pointers are appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at EXT:powermail and the documentation of it. May it brings some of the wanted functions. Or do the whole stuff in your own extension.

Comment: Thanks about the tip for powermail. The finisher looks like something I could use with https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/powermail/stable/ForDevelopers/AddFinisherClasses/Index.html

Comment: I am not sure about choosing between form and powermail. Form is in the core, so I had been thinking tit would be a better choice. It seems like they do basically the same thing. Is that correct?

Comment: @DaleJones The form framework can be extended heavily. You can create your own finishers as well as validators and form elements. It should be no bigger problem to send your form to your own controller. As you said, form is core, powermail is a - very good and maintained - extension.